# Build glsl shader inside CodeXL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In gDebugger you could build the shader inside gDebugger , but I cant find how to do it inside codeXL, I can change the code of the shader but I cant find a build/compile button?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is indeed not supported by CodeXL.